# apache and php response after database commit

Tags: php, apache2

I have a application that send a ajax request to apache server. The php process all data and save in database, than send response to web client.
Sometimes, due to slow networks, the ajax client don't receive this response, ajax get timeout. But data already save in database and the ajax client try resend data generating duplicate entries in database.

There is a way of apache detect that response was not received and return this to php proccess a rollback in database? Or have I implement manually?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php I have never used it though. Otherwise you could try giving each client an UUID and store that value with the inserted row, then give the client a new UUID with the response you return. If you get new request from a client with the exact same UUID you know to ignore it.

Comment: I tried use connection_aborted() and connection_status() before, but is useful on constant data flow and I need just check a unique response.
UUID on the client and server is a solution that works properly.
I have posted here because could exist a solution envolving only php and apache that I didn't know.
Thank you!